# How to assert in cppunit that a statement throws an exception either of type Excp1 or Excp2?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, throw, cppunit

[CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW(Expression, ExceptionType)](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/group___assertions.html#ga7) does not seem to allow checking for exceptions of multiple types i.e. for a statement that can throw more than one kind of exceptions.

For e.x. an expression may throw *Excp1* on one platform, or *Excp2* on another platform. Is there a workaround to test such statements using CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First test, you make your test conditions such that it throws exeption 1.
If it fails to throw, that is a test failure.
if it does throw, you catch it as an exception 1, and accept it as passing.
If it throws something else, the framework catches it.

Second test, you make using conditional compilation to enable code for platform 2 only. You make your test conditions such that it throws exception 2.
IF it fails to throw, that is a test failure.
If it does throw, you catch it as exception 2, and accept it as passing.
If it throws something else, the framework catches it.

On the first platform the test simply passes, as there is nothing for it to do.
On the second platform you catch exception 2 as expected.

Comment: You could make test2 on platform 1 a little bit better by setting the same test condition, and trying to catch exception 2.  If it does, it is a test failure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct support for this feature in cppunit but you have basically two solutions how you can implement it easily in your code.

So the basic idea behind this assert is the following code:

```
bool expected_exception_thrown = false;
try
{
    yourExpression();
}
catch(const ExpectedException&)
{
    expected_exception_thrown = true;
}
catch(...)
{
}

if (!expected_exception_thrown)
     CPPUNIT_FAIL();
```

Of course the actual implementation is a bit fancier and involves some additional features (like better messages for unexpected std::exception and the missing support for an error message) but the general idea is the same.

So now you can easily extend that pattern to support as many exceptions as you need. You can have a look at the existing implementation in [include/cppunit/TestAssert.h](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/cppunit/tree/include/cppunit/TestAssert.h#n510) and either use that implementation and extend it or use the simplified one that I posted above.